# Listar por igual 3 column-count

Tags: php, css, sql, pdo

Bom creio que isso é no css o que não é minha praia, gostaria de estar listando os resultados do bd e passar o próximo resultado para a próxima coluna

tentei usar ( resumido)

```
SELECT * FROM anuncios ORDER BY data DESC

.recipiente{
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-count: 3;
column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 33px;
-moz-column-gap: 33px;
column-gap: 33px; }

<div class="recipiente"> echo " $texto "; </div>
```

sem sucesso, EX: o resultado de uma das linhas da consulta corta na metade e vai para a proxima coluna, até para explicar e meio complicado mais achei um site que retrata bem o que estou querendo fazer

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você consegue confirmar que não é a consulta SQL que está truncando o texto do anúncio (rodando a consulta direto e.g. pela linha de comando ou pelo phpMyAdmin/phpPgAdmin/SQL Management Studio)?

Comment: sim, não é a consulta pois os resultados estao sendo exibindo corretamente,

Answer (score 0):

voce pode quebrar seu texto em colunas, exemplo para quebrar em três:

```
$len = strlen($input);
$space = strrpos($input," ",-$len/3);
$col1 = substr($input,0,$space);
$col2 = substr($input,$space,$space*2);
$col3 = substr($input,$space*2,$space*3);
```

e usar grid `.col-sm-4` do [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

o css disso é simples:

```
.col-md-4 {
    width: 33.33333333%;
    float:left;
}
```